# cURL call in c# bad request

Tags: c#, .net, curl, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to do the following cURL call in a c# .net environment

```
curl -XPOST -d 'Metadata/Type = "sas"' http://bms.org/bcknd/republish
```

The C# code is as follows:

```
var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Metadata/Type", "\"sas\""), });
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://bms.org/bcknd/republish", requestContent);
HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
            Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
}
```

I'm getting a 400 Bad request and when I print it out. Maybe it has something to do with the -XPOST and -d parameter from the curl call?

EDIT: 
Here's the http request from curl:

```
POST http://bms.org/bcknd/republish HTTP/1.1
Host: bms.org/bcknd
User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Metadata/Type = "sas"
```

Here's the http request from my code:

```
POST http://bms.org/bcknd/republish HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: bms.org/bcknd
Content-Length: 43
Connection: Keep-Alive

Metadata/Type = "sas"
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what's actually different between the calls. Perhaps the server doesn't like double quotes? Or it needs a recognizable `User-Agent` ? BTW you can use `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to get the body

Comment: response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() That's the line it throws the exception on. I tried with single quotes too, same result.

Comment: If the request is wrong, or the server down, you'll get an exception no matter what you try. It's *PostAsync* that makes the HTTP call and returns the status code, not `ReadAsStringAsync`. The latter throws though because it can only work if there is an actual body. Use Fiddler to see what's actually sent to the server, and what's different in your call.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've edited the question to include the two requests. Still nothing's coming through. Also when I add -x localhost to the curl call I'm not receiving anything either, but I can see the call in Fiddler.

Comment: What does `still nothing` mean? `Host: bms.org/bcknd` means you are running inside the server. If you pause during debugging, it may be the server application itself that pauses causing an eventual timeout. It also means you can check the logs to see what's going on

Comment: I mean, I step over client.PostAsync and it's waiting without going to the next line, until the task is cancelled. I'm not running my code inside the server though. The server is a separate machine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the HTTP call. If the server is down, you'll get a timeout. If it's frozen because you're debugging its, you'll get a timeout. If it takes too long to respond, you'll also get a timeout. Check the server's logs. Did it get the request? Did it log any errors? Is the server still trying to complete a long running process perhaps and you need to increase the timeout?

Comment: I don't have access to the server logs. The curl call without -x localhost:8888 returns values (invisible in Fiddler). With it, it doesn't (visible in Fiddler). The request from the code is visible in Fiddler but doesn't yield values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185364/discussion-between-ehrendil-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 3):

**Short Version**

Post the data as `StringContent` without url encoding and check the response status before trying to read the response body. *Make sure* the call completes before the application exits, otherwise the call will be cancelled when the application exits. That means, use `async Task` in `Main`, not `async void`  :

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client=new HttpClient();
        var data = new StringContent("Metadata/Type=\"sas\"",Encoding.UTF8,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.google.com/bcknd/republish", data);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var  responseContent = response.Content;
            var body=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(body);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Oops! {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

In cases like this it's *very* important to know what's actually being sent. To do that, one can use a debugging proxy like Fiddler or Charles.

Curl with `-d` sends *unencoded data*. This call :

```
curl -XPOST -d 'Metadata/Type = "sas"' http://bms.org/bcknd/republish
```

will send :

```
POST http://www.google.com/bcknd/republish HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Metadata/Type = "sas"
```

`/` and `"` would have been replaced with other characters if URL encoding was applied. Note also the `User-Agent` and `Accept` headers

If `--data-urlencode` is used, the value will be URL encoded :

```
POST http://www.google.com/bcknd/republish HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 27
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Metadata/Type =%20%22sas%22
```

This code on the other hand :

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var client=new HttpClient();
    var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Metadata/Type", "\"sas\""), });
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.google.com/bcknd/republish", data);
    var  responseContent = response.Content;
    var body=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

Will send :

```
POST http://www.google.com/bcknd/republish HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 25
Host: www.google.com

Metadata%2FType=%22sas%22
```

To get the original payload, one can use `StringContent` with hand-coded content:

```
var data = new StringContent("Metadata/Type= \"sas\"",Encoding.UTF8,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

The request is :

```
POST http://www.google.com/bcknd/republish HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 19
Host: www.google.com

Metadata/Type= "sas"
```

If you want to send the `User-Agent` and `Accept` headers, you can add them to each individual message or as default request headers :

```
var client=new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("curl","7.55.1"));
```

These will add :

```
Accept: */*
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
```

to the request

Comment: So, I've done all this, and I've also caught the request in Fiddler. However, I'm not able to view the request sent from my python application so I can compare it. Any idea why Fiddler isn't catching it?

Comment: @Ehrendil did you add it as a proxy? If your code doesn't use the system's default proxy you'll have to specify it. Typically it's `localhost:8888`. Besides, you need to see what *curl* does. The parameter to set the proxy is `-x localhost:8888`. Note the *lowercase* `-x`

Comment: Does the order of the headers matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can call remote URL as following using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://bms.org/bcknd/republish"))
    {
        request.Content = new StringContent("Metadata/Type = \"sas\"", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Here I have just added reference code, by using that you can create your own. I checked your curl request and [it seems issue it self](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zLUb.gif).

Comment: I was just trying this and I've not been able to get it to work. The application waits at the line with the await for some time and then shuts down with the exception that the task was cancelled. TaskCancelledException

Comment: @Ehrendil that code is no different than your own. If it awaits, it's because the server hasn't responsed or it's blocked, eg because it's being debugged by you or someone else.

Comment: I can do the same call from a python application so I think the server is alright. Perhaps it's the query that's bad since with the original code I posted, I got error 400?

Comment: @Ehrendil what "same call"? The `curl` command line is a plain POST while you tried to post a form. You aren't using the same call

Comment: By "same call" I'm referring to the curl command that I've run separately successfully, this shows me it's not the server's fault, but something is up with this call. I've tried running it with plaintext as you suggested but I still get a TaskCancelledException.

Comment: @Ehrendil `curl` is an application that makes HTTP calls. Fot the HTTP calls to be the same the request text would have to be the same. Is the *User-Agent* the same? The `Accept` header? In any case, `TaskCancelledException` is thrown in case of timeouts or if the application itself terminates. It has nothing to do with the request itself. Use `Fiddler` to see what's actually being sent

Comment: There is issue with `curl` request given by OP in the question! or *may be* firewall of my firm could not allow to call that url

Comment: The curl call is fine. I'm not adding the User-Agent in the header.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're mean by `User-Agent`, there is nothing like that here, [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zLUb.gif)

Comment: @Div What application are you using to view that?

Comment: @Ehrendil the curl call is definitely not fine. `bms.org` fails with a DNS error. It's probably an *internal* URL. And yes, there *is* a `User-Agent` involved. That's why I repeatedly commented that you should use Fiddler to see what's being *actually* sent